# Set up an if else statement to check for query string

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to set up a page that checks for two different query string using an if else statement. It works great as long as I only use one of the if statements and if I put both of them, the one I put on top works while the other one gives me an error. This is the code I've used:

```
if (Request.QueryString.HasKeys())
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        if (Request.QueryString["foo"].Equals("Success"))
            lblUpdate.Text = "Message 1";
        else if (Request.QueryString["bar"].Equals("Success"))
            lblUpdate.Text = "Message 2";
        else
            lblUpdate.Text = "";
    }
}
```

I have tried a few other things but I always run into the same problem, that the 2nd statement doesn't work.

Comment: What's the error? "Doesn't work" isn't very helpful

Comment: **Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

**Exception Details:** System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Then Habib's answer is likely correct... :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should check for `null` first and then compare the value like:

```
if (Request.QueryString["foo"] != null 
     && Request.QueryString["foo"].Equals("Success"))
    lblUpdate.Text = "Message 1";
else if (Request.QueryString["bar"] != null 
    && Request.QueryString["bar"].Equals("Success"))
    lblUpdate.Text = "Message 2";
else
    lblUpdate.Text = "";
```

Since it appears that only one of the query string would be present so you will end up with Null reference exception.

You can also check for contains like:

```
Request.QueryString.AllKeys.Contains("foo")
```

Comment: @Benji, at what line you get the NRE exception. You shouldn't get it on your querystring checks.